# Fault Module Name : tcl85.dll

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an application that was written in python (GUI by Tkinter module).
I run by cmd (ex. python myprogram.py) but when my program open for 1-2 days it has a error "python.exe has stop working"

In error details message in below picture.

[image: error details]

Does anyone know what it mean or how to fix this error?

Comment: it is hard to say anything. `Tkinter` is wrapper on language `tcl` and its module `tk`. Maybe something happened with this file - you could try to reinstall Python and it should reinstall tcl/tk too.

Comment: That's most likely memory mess up (e.g. trying to access memory that was *free*d). These are hard to find bugs, especially without the source code. Does it reproduce on other machines? What are the *Win* and &Python* versions?

Comment: @CristiFati Window Server 2012R2 and python 2.7